Possible implementation of image-set to improve loading performance
The new baseline of September 2023, a new functional notation for CSS is available: image-set. Example usage from MDN include:
.box {
  background-image: -webkit-image-set(
    url("small-balloons.jpg") 1x,
    url("large-balloons.jpg") 2x);
  background-image: image-set(
    url("small-balloons.jpg") 1x,
    url("large-balloons.jpg") 2x);
}

The provided description states:

Resolution and bandwidth differ by device and network access. [...] Resolution can be used as a proxy for filesize.

Therefore, I was trying to implement it in test devices to see if I can improve load time. I am struggling with the resolution definition, and how to efficiently target smaller screen (i.e. mobile users) vs larger screens. And, in general, even on a larger screen, only window size should matter: I wouldn't want the user to download an excessively large picture for nothing.
This has strong impact on full page backgrounds, imaging an element spanning the entire viewport as a splashscreen with a background picture defined only through css.
My test enviroment uses this: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,viewport-fit=cover" />.
How can I target a smaller screen vs a larger screen using the resolution option?

resolution definition

thanks Kosh, but I struggle a lot with resolution definition. How do I convert dpi to screen size for a mobile? I cannot see the connection.

AFAIK, you don't need to, as the browser does it for you, you just provide options. From MDN:image-set() allows the author to provide options rather than determining what each individual user needs.

That is, again, my point. Let's say I have a huge image: 5000px wide. I'd like to serve smaller options for smaller screens. Should I set the 480px wide option to the 1x resolution? to the 96dpi resolution? In the MDN example they have two sizes: small and big. How small is small? How does it correlate to 1x?

image-set does not address your use case. But that shouldn't matter. You can use media queries to select a background image of a suitable size for the device.

@DaemonPainter, e. g. you need to display an image 100x100. For 1x it will be 100x100@96dpi, for 2x -- 200x200@96dpi and so on. (or instead of the size you can adjust image DPI accordingly)
